# Некорректные углы

Tags: unity3d, htc-vive, vr

Я делаю игру с виртуальной реальностью и у меня есть проблемы с поведением объектов. Например когда я подбираю контроллером(`HTC-Vive`) какой то объект и кидаю его, то он улетает влево, вместо того, что бы лететь прямо, при этом траектория верная. Данное поведение не зависит от моего положения в виртуальном пространстве.
Нечто похожее замечено было когда я добавил лазерные указки на контроллер. Они почему то тоже смотрели налево. В редакторе видно, что у игровых объектов, которые отвечают за работу лазерной указки некорректный угол поворота. Пробовал делать тоже самое в пустой сцене, таких проблем не наблюдается.

PS: для работы с устройствами используется SteamVR из ассет стора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь, что у префабов из SteamVR(`[SteamVR]`, `[Status]`, `[CameraRig]`), который используются для контроля и установки точки спавна углы поворота(Rotation) равны 0.0, 0.0, 0.0.